# MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {code: -32603, message: 'Internal JSON-RPC error.'

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, nodejs

This is my first question to community :)

I understand the same question has been asked multiple times, but in most of them I either see no solution to this or its not the problem I am facing.
I am testing the connection of a js script with a smart contract deployed in Ganache.
The package I am using to interact with the Blockchain in ethers.js

**The part of code which invokes the SM**:

```
        let val =  await signer.sendTransaction({
          to: contractAddress,
          gasPrice : 30000,
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
        })
```

**The Smart Contract**:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract EtherWallet {
    address payable public owner;

    constructor(){
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    receive() external payable {} 

    function withdraw(uint _amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner , "Only the Owner can call this method.");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);
    }

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Can You please help me? I am stuck here and so is my project.
Do let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Did you try resetting metamask account nonce?

Comment: Hi Brother! Yes I did. Not helping. Why does this error come? I see many resons and eplainations, but not getting any solution.

Comment: It seems to be an issue between metamask and ganache, one of them isn't providing the data that the other is expecting. I'd reset both, restart ganache, reset the account in metamask and redeploy new contract versions.